# Plugin does not create a custom table upon activation

Tags: plugins, wp-query, customization, table

I have a problem as the title says. My plugin does not create a custom table when it's activated. 
My code is:

```
function bsp_create_update_table() 
{

global $wpdb; //geting the acces to a wp tables
$tablename=$wpdb->prefix . "students"; //the name of a table with it's prefix

//checking if the table with the name we created a line above exists
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$tablename'") != $tablename) 
 {

    //if it does not exists we create the table
    $sql="CREATE TABLE `$tablename`(
    `students_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `students_name` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    `students_lastname` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    `students_email` VARCHAR 850) NOT NULL, 
    `students_course` VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    `students_date` DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (students_id)
    );";

    //wordpress function for updating the table
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
 }
}
```

And I have a hook like this: `register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'bsp_create_update_table');`

When plugin is activated there is no table created and I just don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `register_activation_hook( ... )` in your main plugin file? Or in an `include`'ed one?

Comment: In my main plugin file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answear my question: It's a typo.

```
    `students_email` VARCHAR 850) NOT NULL,
```

should be:

```
    `students_email` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
```

Oh the headache. When the typo is corrected it creates a new table.